# How do you approach when completing the square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization, quadratics, maxima-minima

If $M = 3x^2 - 8xy + 9y^2 - 4x + 6y + 13$, where $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then $M$ must be:

a) positive $\qquad$b) negative $\qquad$c) $0 \qquad$
d) an integer

I somehow managed to figure it out by completing the square but in order to do so, it took me a lot of time and I'm not sure if every time I could solve such problems.

This whole expression can be written as:
$$ 2(x - 2y)^2 + (x - 2)^2 + (y + 3)^2$$
which implies $M$ is positive.

My point is sometimes I'm lucky and I could group them in squares but other times not.
Is there any particular technique/method which always works?

Secondly I also wanna know what you guys observe when completing the squares?

Comment: In my opinion, the key term that must be focused on first is the $8xy$ term.  This is because there seems to be wiggle room everywhere else, re raising/lowering the $x^2$ or $y^2$ terms.  So, the 1st try should be $(ax + by)^2$ where $2ab = 8.$  Then, try to make everything fit around that.

Comment: While you should definitely solidify your ability to pick an approach for the hard math, there is a parallel part of any math problem (especially when applied with units in a real world scenario) that would completely answer this question. You should always ask _Does my answer make sense?_ and that often means getting a rough idea in your head of pos/neg and/or order of magnitude. Use it to validate any calculations. In this case options c and d don't make sense (`x=0.123, y=0.357`). Plus c can't be true without d. Then plug in `y=1, x=1` and you get `3 - 8 + 9 - 4 + 6 + 13 -> positive`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without completing the square, you can also apply the following technique:

$$\begin{align} &3x^2 - 4x(2y+1)+ (9y^2 + 6y + 13-M)=0\\
\implies &\Delta_x=4(2y+1)^2-3(9y^2+6y+13-M)≥0\\ 
\implies &3M≥11y^2+2y+35\\
\implies &3M≥11 \left(y + \frac{1}{11}\right)^2 + \frac{384}{11}\\
\implies &3M≥\frac{384}{11}\\
\implies &M≥\frac{128}{11}>0.\end{align}$$

Comment: Ah nice, $\Delta_x$ is the discriminant of the quadratic in $x$. Nice idea

Comment: As you have used Δ(x) ≥ 0 how can you surely claim that roots of this quadratic in x are always real?

Comment: @Navdeep If the discriminant of quadratic is non-negative, then the roots are always real. This is the fundamental fact about the quadratics.

Comment: I know this fact but how do you know that roots can't be imaginary (in this case)?

Comment: @Navdeep To optimize the polynomial, the roots are considered real.  If we are talking about complex numbers, then $M=0$ can be and $M > 0$ can also be.  It can be $M<0$ too.  So your question loses its meaning.  Notice, when completing the square you assumed that $x,y$ were real. Therefore, I would recommend adding to your question that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Otherwise, the polynomial cannot be optimized.

Comment: @NavdeepSingh - The assumption of the problem is that there are real numbers $x, y$ such that the original equation is true. That value of $x$ is a real root of the quadratic, thus the quadratic has at least one real root.

Comment: @lonestudent I tried your technique to find minimum value of this expression:
b² + 4c² - 4bc + 8b - 16c

When I wrote quadratic in 'b' and solved for Δ≥0, I got 4 ≥ 0
When I wrote quadratic in 'c' and solved for Δ≥0, I got 16 ≥ 0
Which gives nothing. 
What should I do?